# IntelliJ keyboard shortcut for a particular run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a JUnit run configuration to run all my unit tests.

How can I bind a keyboard shortcut to the run of that JUnit config?

Comment: I originally wanted to set shortcuts for my popular run configs, but I've gotten used to using `ctrl + option + r` to bring up the run dialog. It makes it easy to select a recently ran configuration. It's another option to consider.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There is now a third-party plug-in:

- [Run Configuration as Action](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9448-run-configuration-as-action)

Workarounds without plug-ins:

1. Use [Run | Run...](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/invoking-rundebug-actions-in-intellij-idea-9/1.) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>)
   on Windows to quickly select the
   configuration to Run or Debug
2. Run the tests from the Ant script
   target, IDEA allows to assign
   keyboard shortcuts for the selected
   targets in Settings | Keymap.

Comment: Has this changed at all in more recent versions?

Comment: No, but you can work around this with Macros. Check my answer.

Comment: If you do TDD or any other workflow that requires running unit tests often, use the first solution and then each time use Shift+F10 instead, as it repeats the last run - it's slightly faster.

Comment: Please vote for this issue to encourage Jetbrains to prioritize this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69968

Comment: Mac users can use Ctrl+Alt+R, Ctrl+Alt+D instead of Alt+Shift+F10.

Comment: With me on a Mac it's Ctrl+Cmd+R

Answer (score 24):

You can also create a Macro and assign a shortcut to that Macro as a workaround.

1. Go to **Edit | [Macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) | Start recording macro**
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to show Run dialog
3. Start typing the name of the desired **Run Configuration** (Just type enough to distinguish it from other run configurations)
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the **Run Configuration**
5. Go to **Edit | Macros | Stop recording macro** and choose a proper name for recorded macro.
6. Now you can assign a keyboard shortcut to your macro from the **Preferences | Keymap** (Type the name of recorded macro in the search box).

Comment: Nice one. It seems to be fairly flaky, though.  Often it just opens the Run Configuration menu and stops there (at least on my mac).

Comment: Flaky on my linux box too. Opens the run configuration dialog, launch config, but fails to simulate click on the "stop and re-run" alert

Comment: Wow... This is charming. I even removed the devtools

Comment: A tip for auto refresh server. I assigned keymap CTRL+S twice and it saves the page and start rerun.

Comment: This used to work fine for me until IJ 2020.2, now step 3 also types inside the current file, which makes the compilation fail.

Answer (score 17):

I've created plugin for this [Run Configuration as Action](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9448-run-configuration-as-action).
After loading of this plugin it register all Run/Debug configurations as actions. So you can assign shortcut for them, add them to toolbars, etc.
[image]

It works for all Jetbrains IDEs based on IntelliJ platform: CLion, PyCharm, PhpStorm, etc.

Comment: What if I want to use a configuration for Build only? In CLion, there are Build only configuration for CMake and they give error when you want to run it.

Comment: Can you explain, who gives error: CLion? Plugin? For Buid there is should be built-in shortcut.

Comment: Build configurations have no executable. You should use them with "Build" button. *CLion* gives error when you Run it. So,  in the plugin, we need Build items for configuration without executable..

Comment: I'm not familiar with CLion. Is it possible to create run configuration which will run 'Build'? May be as 'Before launch' step? If so - you can assign shortcut to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Infinitest plug into IntelliJ.

*(After installing the plugin from the Plugin Manager, enable the Infinitest facet for your project. Right click on the project, choose facet, add Infinitest.)*

2. To run all tests, Make the project with ⌘-F9 (Mac). This runs all your tests regardless of what the current Run configuration is. You get a nice green message in your face if they pass, a red message also in your face if there's a fail.

It's a bit workaround-y but it works for me. I like that I don't have to engage with any dialogues.