# IntelliJ IDEA: hotkeys for gulp tasks

Tags: intellij-idea, gulp, webstorm, hotkeys

Sometimes it is quite hard to find gulp task in docked window. Is it possible to assign hotkeys for gulp tasks in Idea or Webstorm?

Comment: Press Option+F11 (OS X), or equivalent shortcut on other platforms (look for _Run Gulp/Grunt/NPM task_ in settings/keymap, which will show a pop up list where you can select the task to run (you can start typing to filter the tasks)... Take a look at this post if you want to assign shortcut to particular run configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126187/intellij-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-particular-run-configuration

Comment: @Bohuslav, thank you for the answer. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22952174/4134913) appeared to be a good workaround for my problem.